# Amazon Product API: How to access list of new releases

Tags: ruby, api, amazon-product-api

Amazon has a terrifically useful [search functionality](http://www.amazon.com/s/node=5174&field-date=20120221) where you specify the 'node' id and 'field-date' in order to retrieve the new releases of that particular day. You can even specify what artist you want to [search](http://www.amazon.com/s/node=5174&field-keywords=sleigh+bells&field-date=20120221) for!

However, so far I have been unable to use this specific function in the API through the Ruby [amazon_product](https://github.com/hakanensari/amazon_product) wrapper. When I call the method the web services api disregards the data parameter and simply returns me *all* albums by that particular artist. My expectation is that amazon has turned off the 'date' parameter entirely for the product api; as it is nowhere to be found in the [Product Advertising API Developer guide.](http://s3.amazonaws.com/awsdocs/Associates/2011-08-01/prod-adv-api-dg-2011-08-01.pdf) Yet, does anyone know how to access this functionality or know of other ways to reach the same end result with an entirely different method?

```
req = AmazonProduct["us"]

    req.configure do |c|
      c.key    = 'key'
      c.secret = 'secretkey'
      c.tag    = 'tag'
    end

    res = req.search('Music', :keywords => "sleigh+bells", :date => 20120221)
```

Comment: It looks like they support TimeStamp and not date.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I am afraid TimeStamp is used for authentication; not to specify a specific release date.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/awsdocs/Associates/2011-08-01/prod-adv-api-dg-2011-08-01.pdf#page=63

Comment: Ahh, I did not read close enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're still interested, but I'm looking at how to get this to work too.
Looking at the link provided at the top of your question, the parameter may need to be "field-date", as that is what Amazon has in it's URL.

As you say, I can not find reference of this in the API docs, but you can order by release date, newest first. Then you could store a database of which releases you have seen and then check each one to see if you already have it in your database, if not, it's new new.

Comment: As far as I could find out 'field-date' is not a functional parameter. Instead I have indeed created a database which populates results from a query for every single artist I want to find the new releases of.

This solution, however, is highly impractical as it uses an Amazon API search for every single artist you query.